# Online text of the Officium Parvum

Tags: medieval-latin, religio

What version do you have of the Little Office of the Blessed Virgin Mary (*Officium Parvum Beatae Mariae Virginis*)? I have the one posted on Play Books but it has some errors. Can you show me where the original version is?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you edit your question to give more context? I don't know what *parvum officium* or *BVM* is. Those who can answer probably know, but it'd be nice to make the question clear for the rest of us too.

Comment: Now i know that the online version of this office are wrong. This are rework of IXX century. The original version Is that one of S.Brunonis and the version on Google books  is the only one more appropiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a [PDF of an 1832 edition](https://archive.org/details/officiumparvumbe00cath). I can't vouch for whether it has typographical errors.

Comment: Where can i see It?

Comment: @user3682770 Just follow the link in the answer. The page has an online reader for the book, and there is a pdf download option below it. // Now that you have earned 20 reputation from the question, you can vote up any questions and answers you like. Please also remember to accept an answer if it you got what you wanted. You can learn more about your privileges and site functionality in [our short introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour).